# Is it possible to reconnect a detached and modified folder to a Git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have a folder of source code that was incorrectly file copied without including any internal .git directories, and subsequently modified.  Running git status says "fatal: not a git repository ..."

Is it possible to reconnect this copied directory (and its contents) back to the origin Git repository, or a new branch in that repository?  (and check for any source code changes using git diff, commit/push any worth keeping, etc.)  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: just put the files in place and run `git add` on them.

---

First, let's get a few things out of the way, as otherwise they'll cause confusion.

A *folder* is an OS-level concept: a folder holds sub-folders and/or files.  Git does not store folders.  Git stores commits, and commits store files (only—not folders).

Git stores files in a special, compressed, read-only, Git-only format.  These files have full names—e.g., `a/b/c.ext`.  They don't live in folders, they're just named in a way that your OS may insist needs to be broken up *into* folders.  None of these stored files can ever be changed!  They are frozen for all time.  That's great for archival—for getting to see old versions of files, for instance—but completely useless for getting any *new* work done.  Plus, of course, these frozen files are in a Git-only format.  The rest of the programs on your computer can't use them at all.  The frozen files are buried deep in the `.git` directory/folder that your OS insists that Git must use; here they have weird names, like `11ccea40716d9bbcef731f093e530a9b1aee0013`.  They may even have no obvious name at all (when "packed") but in that case they are still accessible by a database looking using `11ccea40716d9bbcef731f093e530a9b1aee0013` as the key.

In order to let you use, and change and store-new-versions-of, your files, then, Git *must* provide you with a separate work area.  Git calls this work area—the place where Git lets you see and work with your files—the *work-tree* or *working tree*, or any number of similar variants on this name.

Files in this work-tree are not actually being *used* by Git!  They have merely been extracted, typically from some commit.  The commit holds the both the name that Git should use, such as `Makefile` or `builtin/rebase.c`, and the internal weird name by which Git can retrieve the file's data.  Git will extract the file, *creating* any folders if and when the OS demands that Git do so.  For instance, in order for the file to have a name like `builtin/rebase.c`, the OS demands that Git first create a `builtin` folder, if it does not yet exist, so Git will do that.

If you *change* one of these files in any way, you then have to tell Git: *Copy the work-tree version of `Makefile` or `builtin/rebase.c` back into the temporary storage area from which you'll make a new commit.*  You do this with `git add`.

Running `git add path` tells Git: *Hi!  If you have an existing copy of a file with this name, ready to go into the next commit, replace it with the version from the work-tree.  If not, put a copy of the file into the storage area where we're building the next commit.*  This storage area, in which you assemble the new commit, is called—variously—the *index*, or the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*.

You are allowed, at any time, to have files in your work-tree that are *not* in your index.  Files that are in the work-tree, but not in the index, are called *untracked files*.  A whole folder-full of untracked files is often summarized by printing the folder-name instead of all the individual file names, but in fact, it's the files within that folder—using their full names, not the sliced-up folder-ized names your OS demands—that aren't in your index, and hence won't be in your next commit.

You can add this entire folder-full of files with a simple `git add folder`.  Git will read through the folder to find all its files, assemble full names out of them, and `git add` each of those full names to the index, creating a ready-to-freeze-for-all-time copy of the file.  (But see the description of `.gitignore` below.)  Your eventual next `git commit` will then make a new frozen-for-all-time commit.  The new commit, which will become your current commit, will contain every file that was in the index at the time you ran `git commit`, **in the form it has in the index at this time**.

The fact that Git uses the index copy of each file—not the work-tree copy—is why you constantly have to re-`git add` files when you change them.  (There are some shortcuts, like `git add -u` or `git commit -a`, which has Git scan your entire work-tree to look for files that you changed since the index copy, and automatically update them, but that still just really means *update the index first, then commit*)

To get a list of all files that *are* in your index—note that this list can be quite long, and is rarely of any use at all—you can run `git ls-files`.  But instead of doing that, it's usually better to run `git status`.  The `git status` command will:

- First, list the name of the branch you're on, and sometimes a little more information.
- Then, for every file that is in the index, *compare* that file's contents with its counterpart in the current (frozen-for-all-time) commit.  For files that match, say nothing at all.  For files that *don't* match, say that this file is *staged for commit*.  If there are 10,000 files, but only 2 of them don't match, you get a nice short listing telling you that if you commit now, the *new* snapshot has two files that don't match the *old* snapshot.

  For files that are in the current commit and not in the index, call them staged to be deleted.
- Separately: for each file in the index and/or the work-tree, compare the ready-to-freeze index copy to the work-tree copy.  If the two match, say nothing at all.  If they *don't* match, say something: say that this file is *not staged for commit*.

  If there are files that are in the index, but not in the work-tree, `git status` will note them as "deleted".

  If there are files that are in the work-tree, but not in the index ... well, this is where `.gitignore` comes in.  The `git status` command normally complains about these files, saying that they are *untracked*.  That is, after all, the definition of an *untracked file:* it's a file that is in the work-tree, but not in the index.

For a lot of software development, though, it's perfectly normal to have thousands of untracked files.  We need a way to make Git stop complaining about them.  Listing these files, or a name pattern such as `*.o` or `*.pyc` or `__pycache__/`, tells Git: *shut up about these untracked files*.  It also has the  important and useful side effect of telling Git: *If I do an en-masse add of an entire folder-full of files, don't add these to the index if they're not already in the index.*  This means you can usually just `git add .` to add everything: the files that are already tracked get updated if needed, and any *new* files that aren't specifically *ignored* become tracked.

You're going to simply move (or copy) a whole folder-full of files into your work-tree.  These files aren't currently in the index, so they will all be untracked.  You'll simply `git add` them to put the *current* versions in the index.  There will be no previous versions of them—existing commits *cannot be changed* as they are frozen for all time—but they'll be in the *next* commit you make, and continue being in every commit from then on, up until you explicitly *remove* them from the index.

In your case, if your folder-full-of-new-files has some files that should not be tracked, you may want to use `git status` to see which ones are now listed as *untracked*.  If some of those should remain untracked, you can list them in a `.gitignore` file.  *Then* you can do the `git add folder` operation.  If `git status` summarizes them all by showing:

```
Untracked files:
    ...
    folder/
```

you can run `git status -uall` to make Git show you all the file names, rather than summarizing them into a folder-name.

Comment: What do you mean "put the files in place"?  Back into a git-tracked working-directory-tree?  Otherwise, all git commands error in the current copy directory.  Or should I do a git init inside this untracked folder.

Comment: You have a Git repository somewhere, e.g., in `/home/me/src/foo/` which has a `.git/` in it. Just copy the other files there: `cp -r /path/to/files /home/me/src/foo/new`. That creates a `new/` folder containing copies of all the files. This is in your work-tree in that Git repository. All of those files are now untracked.

Comment: How about this?  I move all the files out of the disconnected working folder  (xyz/) into foo/.  Then I git clone a new (old) set into that folder (xyz/).  Then I copy everything back in from foo/, clobbering the same name files that are currently there (in xyz/) with the .git.  Would the copied files now be tracked by git?

Comment: The copied files will now be in the *work-tree* that Git is having you work with. Whether the files are in Git's *index* (in the `.git/index` file) depends on whether the commit that Git checked out *into* that work-tree, earlier, had those files in it. Again, the model is: Git's files are in `.git`, in a Git-ish format that you have no control over. Git lets you muck around with your work-tree, which is in your ordinary computer format. You can do **anything you want** at any time in this work-tree. You can then tell Git: *please look at my work-tree* using `git status` and/or `git add`.

Comment: You do whatever you want, *at any time*, to any files in the work-tree. Git doesn't care. Then you tell Git: *compare your stored stuff to my work-tree* (`git status`), or: *overwrite stuff in my work-tree from your stored stuff* (`git reset --hard`), or: *copy things from my work-tree back into your stored stuff* (`git add`). There are a few more such commands, but in general, the idea is: your work tree is yours to fold, spindle, or mutilate however you wish. Just leave the `.git/*` manipulation to Git itself.

Comment: So, the direct answer to *would the copied files now be tracked by Git* is: *maybe*. A file is *tracked* if and only if it's in Git's index. There was an `xyz/file1` before? That must have gotten there by being copied *from* a commit, *to* the index, then *to* the work-tree. There wasn't an `xyz/file2` before? Well, there's still no `xyz/file2` in Git's index, so `xyz/file2` is *not* tracked. Git doesn't care about folders, only files.

Comment: Got it.  So any added files in the folder could be checked via git status as untracked, and potentially need a git add.  Copies of files with the same name and position copied into the tracked-working folder hierarchy become tracked and can be diff’d and potentially committed.

Comment: Yes, they can be diffed; you'd still have to `git add` them to overwrite the index copy, if they differ and you want the updated one to be committed. You can safely `git add` them to overwrite the index copy if they *don't* differ, too!